# Added some console programs to System PATH, Can't invoke them via the registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry, environment-variables

I added `C:\Tools\scripts\PATH` to my System PATH. It contains a few different console applications that I use frequently.

When I run them from the command-line everything is fine. As an example:

`RunHiddenConsole powershell.exe -file "C:\Tools\scripts\CopyDirStructure.ps1" "C:\Tools\speccy"`

Works completely fine. (RunHiddenConsole is one of the tools in `C:\Tools\scripts\PATH`)

The problem is that this does not seem to work properly in the registry. (I frequently edit my context menus to help with productivity.)

Here's the command:

[image: Registry]

And then I invoke the command:

[image: Context Menu]

And instead of the script running... I just get this:

[image: Generic Dialogue]

I get the same thing even if I completely remove the script from the command key and leave it as just "RunHiddenConsole".

If I enter in the entire executable path, it works. But that completely defeats the purpose of adding it to PATH in the first place.

Do any of you have any idea what's going on? I really can't figure this out.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry command is not run through CMD and therefore is missing
many features, and especially the environment variables that CMD
creates from the registry, most importantly the PATH variable.

You could replace the registry command by
`cmd /c RunHiddenConsole...`,
but that would sort of defeat the purpose of using RunHiddenConsole.

Another possibility is copying RunHiddenConsole to
`C:\Windows\System32`,
which is always searched, although modifying this very important
Windows folder should not be done unless absolutely necessary.

Your best solution is really to specify the whole path to the
RunHiddenConsole program, as the PATH is not very useful in
this case.

Comment: Thank you! That demystifies everything for me. And `cmd /c RunHiddenConsole` is actually a bit better than specifying the entire file path and name I think. A bit of a pain, but I can live with it.